# Encounter error of converting data type nvarchar to numeric while inserting data to temporary table

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

Hello to all members of this  forum, 
I am trying to use following stored procedure for inserting data from main table to temporary table for further analytical purpose:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[terr_punctuality_comp]   AS

Begin

CREATE TABLE #previousdata ( Rly nvarchar(255), preDirect numeric(18,0), preIndirect numeric(18,0), preIncidences numeric(18,0), preTotal numeric(18,0))

INSERT INTO #previousdata SELECT SUM(case when Dir_Ind = 'Dir' then 1 else 0 end ) AS 'preDirect', SUM(case when Dir_Ind = 'Ind' then 1 else 0 end ) + 
SUM(case when rep1 IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end)
+ SUM(case when rep2 IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end)
+ SUM(case when rep3 IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end)
+ SUM(case when rep4 IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end)
+ SUM(case when rep5 IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end)AS 'preIndirect', 
SUM(case when Dir_Ind IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end ) AS 'preIncidences',
SUM(case when Dir_Ind = 'Dir' then 1 else 0 end ) + SUM(case when Dir_Ind = 'Ind' then 1 else 0 end ) + 
SUM(case when rep1 IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end)
+ SUM(case when rep2 IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end)
+ SUM(case when rep3 IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end)
+ SUM(case when rep4 IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end)
+ SUM(case when rep5 IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end)AS 'preTotal', 
Rly FROM  PunctualityMain 

WHERE  Rly IN     ('CR', 'ER', 'ECR', 'ECoR', 'NR', 'NCR', 'NER', 'NFR', 'NWR', 'SR', 'SCR', 'SER', 'SECR', 'SWR', 'WR', 'WCR')   

GROUP BY Rly

end
```

While executing I'm getting

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

My main table structure is

```
ID    int   
Date    datetime    
Train   int 
Dir_Ind nvarchar(255)   
Detn    int 
Rly         nvarchar(255)   
DiV         nvarchar(255)   
rep1    int 
det1    int 
rep2    int 
det2    int 
rep3    int 
det3    int 
rep4    int 
det4    int 
rep5    int 
det5    int
```

sir, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you cannot rely on aliases to set which selected field goes to which table field. Rather you should specify the field order in insert ... select like:

INSERT INTO #previousdata (PreDirect, preIndirect, preIncidences, preTotal, Rly) SELECT ...;

Otherwise the database tries to put the fifth selected field (Rly, which is nvarchar) in the fifth defined field of the table (preTotal, which is numeric).

Comment: Thank you very much. I was such a fool.